# How to copy commits from one branch to another

Tags: git

I have two features I'm working on

Shared -- Commits -- A -- B -- C Feat1

Shared -- Commits -- D -- E -- F Feat2

The problem is that to test Feat2 I really need Feat1 as well, but I still want them as separate branches because they are distinct. What is a good way to make changes to Feat2 and then quickly make a third branch that is both of them together that doesn't require me to destroy it every time.

Shared -- Commits -- Feat1 -- Feat2

What I was doing is

`git checkout feat2
git branch -b combo
git rebase -i feat1`

But then when I make updates to feat2 I don't know how to merge in those new changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Merging

You can merge instead of rebase. Since your combo branch is just for testing, you don't have to worry about the history being a bit messier.

That is:

```
git checkout feat2
git branch -b combo
git merge feat1
```

Later, when you update feat2:

```
git checkout combo
git merge feat2
```

Whenever you make an update to feat1 or feat2, merge that into combo.

The disadvantage is that you'll have to merge all commits in both branches. If there are changes you don't want, you'll have to make a separate commit removing those changes in the combo branch.

### Rebasing

You can rebase the additional commits from feat2 onto combo.

Suppose you add some commits onto feat2, then to move these commits to combo:

```
git rebase --onto combo lastcommittoexcludeonfeat2 feat2
```

Alternatively, before you make the changes to feat2, add a branch or tag, eg:

```
git checkout -b lastfeat2rebase
git checkout feat2
git commit ... # more commits here to feat2
git rebase --onto combo lastfeat2rebase feat2
```

Please note, that once you go with the rebase option, you cannot use the merge option anymore. If you use the merge option, you can later decide to go with the rebase option.

Answer (score 15):

There are basically two options here.

1. You can use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to copy the new commits on `feat2` to `combo`.
2. Instead of rebasing, you can [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

## Cherry Picking

To cherry pick new commits on `feat2` to `combo`, run the following:

```
git checkout combo
git cherry-pick <new commit> <new commit> <new commit>
```

## Merging

Or alternately, you can merge instead of rebasing. E.g. To create combo:

```
git checkout -b combo feat1
git merge feat2
```

Then, to "merge in new changes" from `feat2`, just...

```
git merge feat2
```

Likewise, to merge in new commits on `feat1`:

```
git merge feat1
```

Comment: When I tried to merge I got a fatal: not possible to fast forward error. I tried the cherry picking and the problem is I fixed up the new commit, so I cherry picked a commit it already had but didn't detect the changes, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you merging with `--ff-only`? That's the only reason reason I can think of that git would be complaining about fast forwarding. And AFAIK, none of the methods mentioned in any of these answers will work properly if you're changing history. (Removing commits from `feat1` or `feat2`, not just adding them.) If you need to do that, then really your only option is to recreate `combo` every time you make a change to `feat1` or `feat2`, since the commits `combo` are based off of will suddenly be stale.