# Move top commits of one branch to another

Tags: git

Let say I want to go from

```
                    branch1 <- HEAD
                    ↓
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
     ↑
     branch2
```

to

```
          branch1
          ↓
A -- B -- C
      \-- D' -- E'
                ↑
                branch2 <- HED
```

This can happen when I commit in a branch where I should have committed to another one. I haven't push neither branches yet, so I should be OK moving those `D` and `E` commits from `branch1` to `branch2`.

#### How do I move commits from one branch to another?

One possibility is to cherry-pick and then force moving `branche1` back, but this is ugly:

```
git checkout branch2
git cherry-pick D E
git branch -f branch1 C
```

There should be a rebase possible.

Comment: There is a way to do this via rebase, but it is longer than the concise 3 lines you managed to come up with.  I don't have a problem with doing it your way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is worth an answer if you have time to type it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move commits from one branch to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024374/how-to-move-commits-from-one-branch-to-another)

Comment: @phd Except for the title (which is terrible in suggested dup'), those two questions have nothing in common. The dup' needs merging. I certainly don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of `rebase --onto`: you can rebase a branch on top of any commit. The basic syntax is:

```
git rebase --onto new_base old_base branch
```

In your case you have to move `branch2` first to `branch1`:

```
git checkout branch2
git reset --hard branch1
```

Then move `branch2` to the top of `B`:

```
git rebase --onto B C branch2
```

After this, you have move `branch1` back to `C`:

```
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard C
```

Detailed example:

> The command line argument `--onto` can be passed to git rebase. When in git
>   rebase `--onto` mode the command expands to:
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto
> ```
>
> The `--onto` command enables a more powerful form or rebase that allows
>   passing specific refs to be the tips of a rebase.
>
> Let’s say we have an example repo with branches like:
>
> ```
> o---o---o---o---o master
>                  \
>                   o---o---o---o---o featureA
>                    \
>                     o---o---o featureB
> ```
>
> `featureB` is based on `featureA`, however, we realize `featureB` is not
>   dependent on any of the changes in featureA and could just be branched off
>   `master`.
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto master featureA featureB
> ```
>
> `featureA` is the `<oldbase>`. `master` becomes the `<newbase>` and `featureB`
>   is reference for what `HEAD` of the `<newbase>` will point to. The results are
>   then:
>
> ```
>                   o---o---o featureB
>                  /
> o---o---o---o---o master
>                  \
>                   o---o---o---o---o featureA
> ```

(from [Atlassian Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase), search for `--onto`)

Comment: In the initial setup, `git rebase --onto B D branch2` does not do anything because there are no commits after `D` and before `branch2` in the history line. After you make `branch2` point to `E`, this command moves only the `E` commit on top of `B`.

Comment: Fixed: I forgot that `branch2` is already exist. Just changed the first step to move `branch2` instead of creating it.

Comment: It doesn't fix your rebase. After `git rebase --onto B D branch2`, we get `HEAD -> branch2 -> B`.

Comment: Yeah, I did a mistake: `git rebase --onto B D branch2`, use this instead: `git rebase --onto B C branch2` (fixed in the answer), but the behaviour wokrs. Did yout tryed out on a new repo by commiting `git commit --allow-empty`? Don't do it; add a file which is modified in each commit. If I'm right, Git drops the empty commits when rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rebase interactive:

`git checkout branch1
git rebase branch2 -i HEAD~2`

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Then, the commits are in the order you want. If you want to move the branches to your target, you have to force them (`git branch -f {branch-name} {postition}`)

Comment: `git rebase branch2 -i HEAD~2` _Nothing to do_

Comment: Try with `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Comment: `git rebase -i` can be used to re-order, delete or squash commits. It cannot be used to branch the history line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you don't have uncommitted changes. Either commit or stash them before anything else.

Then create either a temporary branch or a tag that points to commit `E`. If anything goes wrong you can use it (with checkout and reset hard) to restore the position of `branch1` and start over. After you reach the desired outcome you can remove the branch or tag.

You can achieve the desired structure this way:

```
# Make branch `branch2` point to commit `E`
git checkout branch2
git rebase branch1
# Move `branch1` onto its desired destination (2 commits behind its current position)
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard HEAD~2
# Get back to branch2
git checkout branch2
# Rebase its most recent 2 commits (D and E) on top of B
git rebase --onto HEAD~3 HEAD~2
```

Alternatively you can rephrase the last command as `git rebase --onto branch1~1 branch1`.

It moves the commits that are reachable from the current branch (`branch2` that points to commit `E`) but are not reachable from branch `branch1` on top of commit `branch1~1` (the parent of `branch1`). This way, the history line that starts from `branch1` (except `branch1`) is moved as a sibling of `branch1` (or wherever the argument of `--onto` says).

Read the [documentation of `git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for more information about how `git rebase` works.

Comment: You are right, it seems I didn't notice the presence of `branch2` in the initial shape of the question. Maybe I need a better pair of glasses? :-)

Comment: Well, it should work (and do what you need) **because** I already moved `branch1` to commit `C` :-). Create a temporary branch (or create a tag) on commit `E` and give it a try. The temporary branch or tag is an easy way to revert to the initial status in case something does not work as expected.